# Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation - Test Project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, mstest

In my visual studio, when I am trying to run Test Project it is throwing this exception - Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

Previously, I used to connect to TFS through this. Now, I do not have access to connect.

I am running Visual Studio 2010. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by downloading and installing Team Explorer 2010 http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=329 somehow it repaired things.

Also, some people report that running `devenv /resetuserdata` from a VS command prompt can help. did not work for me.